# plugin component list cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

this is probably very easy to do, but I can't seem to figure it out. How do I get the list of **components** of a **plugin** in a cakePHP application (I just want the components' class names).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in 1.3 this should work:

```
App::objects('PluginName.Component');
```

but you can always get the path:

```
$path = CakePlugin::path('PluginName');
```

and manually iterate over the components folder.